# Consistent Knockback Direction Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, I am programming a top-down game where if the player does damage to an enemy, the enemy would be knocked back opposite of the direction of the attack. The code I currently have moves the enemy downwards, regardless of the position of the player's attack. This game was created in Unity3D. The enemy has a CharacterController component attached to it.

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
//...
   Vector3 knockBack = col.transform.position - transform.position; //Used to calculate the direction of the knockback.
    GetComponent<CharacterController>().Move (knockBack);
//...
}
```

I am sure I am missing something, but what? I have tried using the rotation of the objects, and the -transform.forward of the player, but it does not seem to have an effect on the direction of the movement. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Vector subtraction (like normal subtraction) is not commutative have you tried switching it around (or Debug.Log it)? Also keep a reference to CC stored you probably need it more than once anyway.

Comment: That subtraction is most likely the problem. If you want to have a vector from `a to b`, then it is always `b - a`.

Comment: Also, since you said top down, you might want to restrict one of the axis if you have no elevation.

Comment: And another also, make sure that the knockback is not manipulated by other movement.

Comment: @yes and Gunnar B. - Thank you for your help. I have switched it to transform.position - col.transform.position. It now moves in more directions than just straight down, but it still moves in the opposite direction of what I desire. For example, a hit from the left moves it to the left, while I want it to move to the right. I tried using the opposite (-) form of the result, but that just results in it going straight back down again. Any advice?

Also, there are no currently active movement manipulators.